# Laravel Belongs to Many Through multiple

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have the following table structure

**turns**
id

**orders_payments**
id
turn_id
order_id

**orders**
id

And I want to get all orders related to a turn

so

```
Class Turn{
  public function orders(){
      return ????
  }

}
```

How can you achieve that?
I tried the `hasmanythrough` but it only works when the relations are in cascade

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure `hasManyThrough('Order', 'order_payment')` didn't work?

Comment: No it doesn't work, it search for `GS_orders.order_payment_id` which doesn't exist,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wonder why you make your life hard and call your model `Turn` and the pivot table `order_payment` ?

Anyway, you want this:

```
// Turn model
public function orders()
{
   return belongsToMany('Order', 'order_payment');
   // in case you would like to call your fkeys differently, use this:
   // return belongsToMany('Order', 'order_payment', 'payment_id', 'order_whatever_id');
}

// Order model
public function turns() // or payments() ?
{
   return belongsToMany('Turn', 'order_payment');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Order');
}
```

Then you can do

```
$orders = Turn::find(1)->orders;
```

Comment: This would work if in `turn` I had the `order_id` field, but in my case this is stored in `order_payment` not in `turn` directly

Comment: That would be true for a `belongsTo` relationship. Since you have a `belongsToMany` relationship, you only need the pivot table, which should be called `order_turn` if you follow the default Laravel naming convention. More info can be found here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

Answer (score 1):

As @lowerends points out, this is a BelongsToMany relationship, since I was using the orderPayments table for more things I didn't notice it until he said, so finally the solution is the following

```

```
public function orders(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Order','orders_payments','turn_id','order_id');
}
```

```

Comment: Table name is wrong and the keys are in wrong order in your example.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk_deczo_ you were right, just updated it